# Ask for user location authorisation without getting it

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager

I would like to ask the user for his permission when the app is loaded, but to get the location later on. I realise this can be done in iOS 8, but in iOS 7 as far as I have researched permission will be asked for automatically when you start updating location.
So in iOS 8

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

and then you can get the location,
but in iOS 7 authorisation is required only on

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want don't get the location immediately?

Comment: I would like to ask the user know that this app uses location when he first launches the app.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981679/ios-waiting-for-location-manager-to-init). The basic idea is...to let iOS 7.x do it's thing. For iOS 8.x, handle location authorisation changes in (1) `CLLocationManagerDelegate` (2) Custom observer for changes in authorisation. This is exactly how I have managed location services in my app for uniformity across iOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2:** Have a look at [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/).

It's important to note that **you're not going to have identical behaviors with different APIs. The iOS 8 API was designed to be different.**

If you want your app to appear to behave identically on both `iOS 7` and `iOS 8`, you can show some UI to inform the user that they need to enable location. In my apps, I do this with a button in a welcome walkthrough. You might put this button in a menu or whatever.

When the user taps the button, I handle the logic flow as I described above, except if the authorization changes, I'll begin location updates on `iOS 8`, instead of ending them.

```
if (iOS8) {
   // Request permission
}
else {
   // Begin updates - implicitly ask for permission
}

// .... In authorization did change:
[manager startUpdatingLocation]; // By now, both versions have permission and are ready to update.
```

This way, you have the same behavior, even if the code paths are a little different.

I have a class that handles all of the logic for me, and it can behave as a singleton or as individual instances. Have a look at it [on GitHub (link)](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBPlacePickerController) if you'd like.

**Original Answer:**

If you are concerned about battery, I'd suggest triggering updates on iOS 7, and then disabling location when your permissions change, or when you get a location.

From the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:):

> This method is called whenever the application’s ability to use location services changes. Changes can occur because the user allowed or denied the use of location services for your application or for the system as a whole.

So do something like this:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
else 
{
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Then, in your `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` implementation, you can call stopUpdatingLocation.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
```

didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }

You might even "get away" with no location updates being successfully triggered that way. It's unclear why you want to defer location updates, but this is one way to do it.

Comment: It's not about battery. I would just like the app to behave identically in both iOS 7 and iOS 8

Comment: Thanks. Although it feels a bit like a workaround, it seems this is the only way to do what i want. I Will try your way and let you know

Comment: Good luck. It's not a workaround,though. It's what happens when you provide legacy support to an API that's been improved for user privacy.

Comment: Location updates still got triggered. I just made my UI to ask the user to go to settings and switch location services later on.

Comment: Why would you want to make your user go around your app and manually enable something when you can do it yourself?

Comment: Putting myself as the user, I would think that allowing to get location and actually getting location are totally different things. This is why I would like to separate this two things, but it seems like the API is just not designed like that.

Comment: Technically, you're right, but the conventional way of getting permissions is to present users with the context where they need location, photos, contacts access, etc, and then immediately utilizing it. That way, users understand why you asked for a specific permission and aren't creeped out by you asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call startUpdatingLocation when you launch. When you get a location just stop updating.

Comment: It feels like the user won't know his location is being acquired at that time. And I would like the app to behave identically in both iOS 7 and iOS 8

Comment: If you just call `startUpdatingLocation` on launch, iOS 8 will log an error about requiring permissions and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

This way, you don't need to know (or care) what operating system is being used. Your only concern is whether or not the selector (or class) you want to implement is supported.

Comment: This won't ask for permission in iOS7

Comment: The permission for location services in iOS7 and earlier is handled by the system. You don't need to handle that.

Comment: That is correct, but it seems like you did not understand my question. I am looking for a way to just ask for authorisation, but actually get the location later on in iOS7. In iOS 8 this seems to be possible.

Comment: I would not recommend trying to get iOS7 to pose as iOS8. Apple doesn't like it when we try to override a system level event, unless we have a very good reason. Also it's not advisable to start location services at launch unless location services are needed. To use this as a workaround is clumsy at best. If iOS7 or earlier, just let the system handle the permissions.